# Hibernate, Use a constant in a many to many join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, many-to-many, constants

I have a many to many join that I am trying to use in Hibernate with the following tables;

```
CREATE TABLE media (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
   file longblob COMMENT 'Content of the file if it is embedded',
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE media_reference (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  media_id INTEGER NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the media',
  reference_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  reference_type VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE people (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  reference_type VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'People',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Basically, the people records can be linked to many media records and the media records can be linked to many people records.

I have used a 'reference_type' field in the 'media_reference' table to store the name of the table that the relationship pertains to because I want to be able to use the same mechanism to associate media records with records in other tables.  The combination of the reference_type and reference_id is used to get the media_reference records.

I have spent days going around in circles trying all sorts of ways to get this to work. I am quite new to Hibernate so I'm not sure even what questions to ask and it therefore takes me ages to find a way forward.

The code below works in as much it does what I want it to.  I can add media records to people records when I am updating or creating them.  The thing I don't like about the code is the need to have a reference_type field in the people table.  This is because it is always going to be the same but I couldn't work out any other way to get the name of the table into the media_reference.reference_type field.

Ideally in the @ManyToMany annotations in PeopleEntity class I would be able to specify a constant for the reference_type @JoinColumn but as far as I can tell you can't use formulas in a JoinColumn.

So basically I want to be able to do a Many To Many join using a constant value as part of the Join.  Or if there is another way to do the whole thing I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

## The code

**PeopleEntity.java**

```
package com.company.system.hibernate.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class PeopleEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4550422780535557785L;

    private String name;
    private Set<MediaEntity> media = new HashSet<MediaEntity>(0);
    private Integer id;
    private String referenceType = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 250)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable (name = "media_reference",  joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="reference_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true),
            @JoinColumn(name="reference_type", referencedColumnName="reference_type", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<MediaEntity> getMedia() {
        return this.media;
    }

    public void setMedia(Set<MediaEntity> media) {
        this.media = media;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "reference_type", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getReferenceType() {
        return referenceType;
    }

    public void setReferenceType(String referenceType) {
        this.referenceType = referenceType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof PeopleEntity)) return false;
        final PeopleEntity other = (PeopleEntity) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id) &&
                Objects.equals(this.name, other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PeopleEntity{" +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }
}
```

**MediaReferenceEntity.java**

```
package com.company.system.hibernate.entities;
    
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "media_reference")
public class MediaReferenceEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4550422780535557785L;

    private Integer id;
    private Integer referenceId;
    private String referenceType;
    private MediaEntity media;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public MediaEntity getMedia() {
        return media;
    }

    public void setMedia(MediaEntity media) {
        this.media = media;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "reference_id", length = 0, precision = 0)
    public Integer getReferenceId() {
        return referenceId;
    }

    public void setReferenceId(Integer referenceId) {
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "reference_type", length = 0, precision = 0)
    public String getReferenceType() {
        return referenceType;
    }

    public void setReferenceType(String referenceType) {
        this.referenceType = referenceType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MediaReferenceEntity{" +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", referenceId='" + referenceId + '\'' +
                ", referenceType='" + referenceType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MediaReferenceEntity that = (MediaReferenceEntity) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(id, that.id)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(referenceId, that.referenceId)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(referenceType, that.referenceType)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(media, that.media)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(media, referenceId, referenceType);
    }
}
```

**MediaEntity.java**

```
package com.company.system.hibernate.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * <p>MediaEntity class.</p>
 */
@Table(name = "media")
@Entity
public class MediaEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1915301587741334140L;

    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private byte[] file;

    @Column(name = "file", length = 2147483647, precision = 0)
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    @Transient
    public InputStream getFileStream() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(file);
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it won't be a problem if you duplicate the relationship table:

```
TABLE MEDIA (
   MEDIA_ID PK
)
```

---

```
TABLE MEDIA_PEOPLE (
   MEDIA_ID FK
   PEOPLE_ID FK
)

TABLE PEOPLE (
  PEOPLE_ID PK
)
```

---

```
TABLE MEDIA_CARS (
  MEDIA_ID FK
  CARS_ID FK
)

TABLE CARS (
  CARS_ID PK
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Your solution is nice and simple and would work and the more I think about it the more I like it.  The thing I was trying to achieve was to have a general purpose join table so if I wanted to be able to add media to another table all I had to do was paste the getter and setter with the hibernate annotations into the entity and it would work.

Comment: I couldn't get it working any other way in the time I had so I have used the method Marcelo described.  Thanks for your help.